# Peer to Peer Replication in MS SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, transactional-replication

Is it good practice to use Peer to Peer Replication in MS SQL 2022 (Enterprise Edition) within Windows 2019 Server (three servers)?
I want to create three replicas of my client's database and to use those databases participating actively in a Hospital ERP System.

Comment: More information needed. How many database objects need to be replicated? Do you plan to write data to the other replicas or only read from them? How big is the database roughly? How often does data change?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Yes, I want to write data to the other replicas. Database size is 300GB. Data changes are frequent.

Answer (score 2):

> to use those databases participating actively in a Hospital ERP System.

This is almost certainly not supported by the ERP vendor and will cause problems.

A much simpler and better-performing option is to use [Availability Groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/overview-of-always-on-availability-groups-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16) to create multiple replicas of the database, and make some of them available for read-only access.

If you don't need high availability and automatic failover, you can simply create a [readable replica](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/read-scale-availability-groups?view=sql-server-ver16) on another server.

Comment: I want to write data to the other replicas. Database size is 300GB. Data changes are frequent. Which replication should I choose??

Comment: AlwaysOn AG replica, and only write to the primary.  No multi-master replication is going to work or be supported by third-party packaged applciations.